# Google gson handle json with different types

Tags: java, gson

I have following json to prase and convert to POJO.

```
{
    "name" : "test",
    "parameters":[
    {"key":"p1","value":["array of strings"]},
    {"key":"p2","value": "some string value"}
    ]
}
```

As you can see the parameters key is an array of objects(key value pair) where "value" can be of two types (an array or string). 
My POJO for key value pair object looks like this -

```
public class KeyValuePair {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
}
```

This works great when all objects in "parameters" array are of string type but it breaks if I get an array of string with error:

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 261 path $.parameters[0].value

How can I handle both types?

Answer (score 0):

You can check value's value type while parsing.

Like this...

```
if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
// It's an array
// store in arrray
} else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
// It's an object
// store in object
} else {
// It's something else, like a string or number
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: So I need to do manual parsing? I was hoping if there was way to handle this automatically when using like gson.fromJson("json", MyPojo.class)

Comment: As you have used "Object" for value is the only way to store String or Array which is not working as you have mentioned. Then one way left that is manual parsing according to me.

Answer (score 0):

This Pojo has problem and Gson couldn't parse it  use this POJO

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class KeyValuePair {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@SerializedName("parameters")
@Expose
private List<Parameter> parameters = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<Parameter> getParameters() {
return parameters;
}

public void setParameters(List<Parameter> parameters) {
this.parameters = parameters;
}

 }
-----------------------------------com.example.Parameter.java-----------    ------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Parameter {

@SerializedName("key")
@Expose
private String key;

@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private String value;

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

or using this site to generate POJO based on your json [JsonToPojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Bigoloo has the right approach. However it is enough to just change the POJO as:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MysticalObject {
    private String name;
    private Collection<Object> parameters;
}
```

and then:

```
MysticalObject mo = new Gson().fromJson( json, MysticalObject.class );
```

so you should not need to create any `Parameter` class. Just when getting the value from `Collection parameters` check if it is of type `String` or `String[]`.

Parameters will be a `Map` - `LinkedTreeMap` in my case - so you can get parameters from it also by keys `p1` and `p2`.